# How to add an image to the header of MVC3 Grid - @grid.GetHtml?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc

I just want **to add some image to the MVC3 Grid header** to click on it and sort rows as it works for the normal header text.

How I can do it?

Thank you!

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
                            tableStyle: "grid",
                            headerStyle: "head",
                            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                            rowStyle: "row",
                            selectedRowStyle: "selected-row",
                            columns: grid.Columns(

                                           grid.Column("SportName", "Sport", style: "column"),
                                           grid.Column("City", "City", style: "column"),
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "click on it and sort rows." Are you looking to have arrows which show the ascending and descending sort? http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012308-1.aspx

Comment: @JasCav Yes yes Put it as your answer I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @JasCav, I think he is asking about the ASP.NET MVC `WebGrid` helper. Nothing ti do with `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` which is a classic WebForms control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request in the comments, here is the answer to your question.

Since you are looking for the arrows for ascending and descending sort, that information can be found at this [4guysfromrolla tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210323170551/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012308-1.aspx).

The key portion is found in overriding what happens on sorting.

```
public class GridView : System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView
{
   protected override void OnSorted(EventArgs e)
   {
      string imgArrowUp = ...;
      string imgArrowDown = ...;

      foreach (DataControlField field in this.Columns)
      {
         // strip off the old ascending/descending icon
         int iconPosition = field.HeaderText.IndexOf(@" <img border=""0"" src=""");
         if (iconPosition > 0)
            field.HeaderText = field.HeaderText.Substring(0, iconPosition);

         // See where to add the sort ascending/descending icon
         if (field.SortExpression == this.SortExpression)
         {
            if (this.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
               field.HeaderText += imgArrowUp;
            else
               field.HeaderText += imgArrowDown;
         }
      }

      base.OnSorted(e);
   }
}
```